# Measurability of piecewise defined function on a product space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, product-space

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ and $(X,\mathcal X)$ be measurable spaces
- $g_n:\Omega\times X\to\mathbb R$ be $\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal X$-measurable for $n\in\mathbb N$

Assume that for all $x\in X$, there is a $N_x\in\mathcal A$ such that $(g_n(\omega,x))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is convergent for all $\omega\in\Omega\setminus N_x$. Now, let $$g(\omega,x):=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(\omega,x)&&\text{, if }\omega\in\Omega\setminus N_x\\0&&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}$$ for $(\omega,x)\in\Omega\times X$. How can we conclude that $g$ is $\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal X$-measurable?

My problem with this task is the dependence of $N_x$ on $x$. How do we need to argue?

Comment: This is not true the way it is stated. Take $X$ any uncountable space with the countable/co-countable $\sigma$-algebra, and $g_n=1$. The diagonal $\Delta_X=\left\{(x,x):x\in X\right\}$ is not measurable, but we could choose $N_x=\left\{x\right\}$, so $g$ is the characteristic of the diagonal, not measurable. If instead we had that $N_x$ was **the whole set** for which $(g_n(\omega,x))_n$ converges, and it was measurable, then the result could be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true the way it is stated. Take $X$ any uncountable space with the $\sigma$-algebra of countable/co-countable subsets, and let $g_n=1$ on $X\times X$.

The diagonal $\Delta_X=\left\{(x,x):x\in X\right\}$ is not measurable, but we could **choose** $N_x=\Omega\setminus \left\{x\right\}$, so $g$ is the characteristic of the diagonal, not measurable.

---

If we instead take $\Omega\setminus N_x=\left\{\omega:(g_n(\omega,x))_n\text{ converges}\right\}$ (so we are **not making a choice depending on $x$**), then $N_x$ is simply the $x$-section of the complement of $N'=\left\{(\omega,x):(g_n(\omega,x))\text{ converges}\right\}$, which is measurable.

This becomes a particular case of the following fact, with $\mathcal{Y}=\Omega\times X$:

- If $\mathcal{Y}$ is a measurable space and $f_n$ is a sequence of real measurable functions on $\mathcal{Y}$, then $C=\left\{y:(f_n(y))_n\text{ converges}\right\}$ is measurable, and $\lim_n f_n$ is measurable on $C$.

Comment: $g$ is a characteristic of diagonal. Why is $g$ not measurable ?

Comment: @HKLee Because a characteristic function of a set $A$ is measuarable iff the set $A$ is measurable...

Comment: @HKLee This is a standard example that is always good to keep in mind. You can prove, for example, that for every $A$ in the product $\sigma$-algebra, either $A$ or $A^c$ is contained in a countable union of vertical and horizontal lines, $\left\{x\right\}\times X$ or $X\times\left\{x\right\}$ (prove that this latter condition defines a $\sigma$-algebra containing all rectangles). The diagonal doesn't satisfy this property.

Comment: Your measurability claim "$\lim_nf_n$ is measurable on $C$" has to be understood with respect to the trace $\sigma$-algebra, right?

Comment: Oh, and note that the $N_x$ in my question is such that $(g_n(\omega,x))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is convergent on the complement $\Omega\setminus N_x$, while you define it to be the set of convergence.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Ah yes. Doesn't make much difference since we can always take complements in $\sigma$-algebras, but that's right. Fixed it.